# RestSharp: is it possible to change the http version?

Tags: c#, http, restsharp

Is it possible to change the http protocol version used by RestSharp? i.e. I'm guessing the default is 1.1, I want to change it to 1.0.

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: @MarkNottingham - I'm building GUI http client backed by RestSharp and, though I have no personal need for http 1.0 at this time, I figure there may be some occasion where I or someone else may need that option (indeed, at my office, we still have some servers running late-90s era classic ASP internal applications). Note that .NET's own http API supports it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpversion.aspx

Comment: HTTP/1.1 is backwards compatible; the only reason you'd want to be able to change the version is to do *very* specific HTTP conformance testing...

Answer (score 0):

```
var client = new RestClient(url);

client.ConfigureWebRequest(r => { r.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10; });
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the **how** is important, but a great part of the quality level of the site comes from the fact that people go to great lengths to explain the **why**. While a _code-only_ answer get the person who asked the question past whatever hurdle they might be facing, it doesn't do them or future visitors much good in the long run. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).